# Time complexity of this code sample

Tags: c, data-structures, big-o

```
i=n;

while (i>=1) {

  --x=x+1;

  --i=i/2;

}
```

What is the running time of this code?

> A O(N^2)
>
> B O(N^3)
>
> C O(N^4)
>
> **D O (LOG N)**
>
> E O(2^N)

I believe it is the option D

This is for revision. Not homework

Comment: I don't believe you. You have three questions, two on this, and one on quicksort.

Comment: Are you sure that while condition is correct? This is an infinite loop as `i` will always been at least equal to `i`. Plus, if it's revision then you already have the answer somewhere ;)

Comment: `while (i>=i)` is equivalent to `while(true)`, so I guess you've made a mistake, no?

Comment: Pick an `n`, e.g. `256` and run this algorithm by hand. What is the value of `x` afterwards? What do you notice?

Comment: all for revision. exam is on friday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will never terminate as the while condition is

```
i>=i
```

However, assuming you wanted to type

```
i>=1
```

The answer will be log(n).

Comment: does this line i=i/2; lead us to O(logn)?

Comment: Yes. On the `k`th loop iteration you are effectively dividing the original `i` by `2^k`.

Answer (score 0):

Your belief would be correct if you change the while condition to `i>=1`
As it stands the complexity is O(INFINITY)